Google authentication indie docker with ASP.NET Core razor pages
I'm having an issue: I have an ASP.NET Core 8 razor pages web app that I have run in a docker container.
My configuration is to use Google Authentication which works fine outside docker.
Here is my config section:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = "myClientId";
    options.ClientSecret = "myClientSecret";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.Events.OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = context =>
    {
       context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri + "&prompt=consent");
       return Task.CompletedTask;
    };

});

I'm trying to run this app in Docker on a Linux host behind nginx.
I pointed my domain to my http port in Docker. When I'm trying to log in with Google account, I get an error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
When I checked, it sends me http://example.com/signin-google as return URL instead of https://example.com/signin-google.
After searching for a while, I found that I should set forward headers:
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions { ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto });

But even with adding those, I could not fix this issue. I need some help to figure this out - how should I fix it?

Thats an issue with docker i think.

@LindaLawton-DaImTo if i could set the schema when I AddGoogle() i could fix the problem. but it seems it does not provide anything to set a full domain.

redirect uri is configured by the application when its run if the application is running http then its going to say http.

@LindaLawton-DaImTo what if i have multi tenant app?

then you add multiple redirect uri's

After digging more into GoogleHandler handler class i came across this answer
this is how i fixed it.

i made class and inherit that from GoogleHandler class and override BuildChallengeUrl method
 public class ReplacedGoogleHandler : GoogleHandler
 {
    public ReplacedGoogleHandler(IOptionsMonitor<GoogleOptions> 
           options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) 
    : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

 protected override string BuildChallengeUrl(AuthenticationProperties 
 properties, string redirectUri)
 {
     var uri = new Uri(redirectUri);
     string port = uri.IsDefaultPort ? "" : $":{uri.Port}";
     string secureUri = $"https://{uri.Host}{port}{uri.PathAndQuery}";
     return base.BuildChallengeUrl(properties, secureUri);
 }
}


then i added this to my startup class after my Google config (AddGoogle)
builder.Services.AddTransient<GoogleHandler, ReplacedGoogleHandler>();



this worked perfectly for me.
